# SpringBoot test module doesn't search log4j2 configuration in the right classpath

Tags: java, testing, logging, spring-boot, log4j2

I'm having some problems running tests in my SpringBoot project.

The project-structure is the following:

[Project Structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yneGW.jpg)

I can start the resourceService without issues, but if i even try to run the standard test of SpringBoot projects.....

```
package com.pcsystem;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ResourceserviceApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

the program respond with this error:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'resourceservice/log4j2.xml'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\java\IntelliJ_projects\baseprojectoauth2\resourceservice\resourceservice\log4j2.xml (Unable to find the specified classpath)
```

So i tried to change the application.properties specific property from

```
logging.config=resourceservice/log4j2.xml
```

to

```
logging.config=log4j2.xml
```

After the change i've noticed that resourceserviceApplication will not start because it can't find the log4j2.xml:

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'log4j2.xml'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\java\IntelliJ_projects\baseprojectoauth2\log4j2.xml (Unable to find the specified classpath)
```

I've tried to resolve in many ways and doing a lot of researches but at the moment i'm still stuck here.

Any idea?

ps: it seems that the Authorizationservice module doesn't suffer the same problem, but simply because i haven't set the logging.config property in Authorizationservice's application.properties (there is no need for now)

Thanks in advance and have a great day.

**-UPDATE 1-**

Configuration file is about all the resourceService module, so i've done as you said Kostiantyn ( thanks for you response ) but the problem still persist.

Actual situation:

[Project structure after your reply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ncb3w.png)

Now resourceServiceApplication won't start , saying :

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'log4j2.xml'
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\java\IntelliJ_projects\baseprojectoauth2\log4j2.xml
```

and the contextLoads() method from the test package says:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\java\IntelliJ_projects\baseprojectoauth2\resourceservice\log4j2.xml
```

Let me show you configuration file:

```
server.port=8888

logging.config=log4j2.xml

spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.database=jogging
#spring.data.mongodb.username=admin
#spring.data.mongodb.password=pass
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

As requested from user1615664 , below you can see my gradle file
(that's the gradle file about the resourceService module; 
 AuthorizationService have one specific gradle file and lastly there is 
 a root gradle file, that i will show to you at the end of this update)

Exscuse me for the lenght, i'm using a large number of libraries here.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    compile.exclude group:'ch.qos.logback'
}

dependencies {


    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web') {
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude module: "logback-classic"
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2')

    compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika', version: '1.16', ext: 'pom'
    compile group: 'org.apache.tika', name: 'tika-parsers', version: '1.16'
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")


    //compile project(':authorizationservice')
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.hateoas/spring-hateoas
    compile group: 'org.springframework.hateoas', name: 'spring-hateoas', version: '0.23.0.RELEASE'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.6'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security.oauth', name: 'spring-security-oauth2', version: '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-jwt', version: '1.0.8.RELEASE'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis
    compile group: 'org.apache.axis', name: 'axis', version: '1.4'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/axis/axis-jaxrpc
    compile group: 'axis', name: 'axis-jaxrpc', version: '1.4'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-discovery/commons-discovery
    compile group: 'commons-discovery', name: 'commons-discovery', version: '0.5'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxrpc-api
    compile group: 'javax.xml', name: 'jaxrpc-api', version: '1.1.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlrpc/xmlrpc
    compile group: 'org.apache.xmlrpc', name: 'xmlrpc', version: '3.1.3', ext: 'pom'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation
    compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail
    compile group: 'javax.mail', name: 'mail', version: '1.4.7'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/wsdl4j/wsdl4j
    compile group: 'wsdl4j', name: 'wsdl4j', version: '1.6.3'



    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

**PS:** maybe is worthless , but in the root module ( baseProjectOauth2 )
we can admire this root gradle file

```
group 'com.pcsystem'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Comment: Please share the Gradle file. I think you do not properly mark the resources folder.

Comment: Updated the post. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel greedy replying to my own question, but i think i've solved.

I've done these things:
-> created resource folder under test module

```
src
    main
    test
        java
        resources
            application.properties
```

In that properties file i've only put this setup

```
logging.config=log4j2.xml
```

And all i have to say now is
["explicative image here"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqCo7.jpg)

Simply i have to deep study spring structure (and even gradle one) about auto detect of properties files

Answer (score 6):

You've missing `src/test/resources` folder in your project structure, and looks like current location of `log4j2.xml` in the project root is not under classpath at all

Rely on Gradle project convention and place your config files accordingly, i.e. create either src/test/resources and put file in there, if your logging configuration is *test specific*:

```
src
   test
      java
         ...
      resources
         log4j2.xml
```

Or, if logging configuration inside your `log4j2.xml` will be used by your application during live run (included into .jar deliverable), move this file to `src/main/resources` instead

that will bring your `logging.config=log4j2.xml` working.

Further reading about Gradle project structure & resources folders is [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_java_projects.html#sec:a_basic_java_project)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put value `classpath:log4j2.xml` instead of just `log4j2.xml` into your application.properties (or application.y[a]ml) file.

All the resources, including this file, should be placed inside the `src/main/resources` (where application.properties file is also placed). Regardless of a few possible exceptions.

If you want a different configuration of logging for tests, than you should put adapted file inside of tests' resources directory (`src/test/resources`), but if you want these to be the same, then you can leave it as is (inside `src/man/resources` only)